# Debug 16-bit MS-DOS Subsystem error

Tags: assembly, windows-xp, virtualbox, dos

I've been doing simple debugging using MS-DOS's debug command in VirtualBox and while doing so I've encountered an error:

[image: Screenshot with error message]

It appeared after I tried to use the g (go) command to execute the program. I would really like some help on how to solve this error so I can execute the program.

Comment: Looks like your code may have jumped off where it doesn't belong. It's not clear what code was executing at the time right before the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the plain `A` command. Don't specify a segment.

[image: MS-DOS screen]

Comment: May I ask how do I set the save location of the sam1.com, I tried -n Z:\ and -n Z: but it gives file creation error, I wanted to put the files to my host, please refer to this screenshot. I also tried -n sam1.com but it went to the c drive of the VM. I know I can just move it manually but I want to know how to do it in the code.  http://imgur.com/fYzuSRt